# `Corrupted state at` after runtime upgrade to `0.9.16` on `rococo-local` chain

Tags: polkadot, runtime, rococo

I'm facing some strange logs when doing a runtime upgrade a Polkadot `rococo-local` relay chain to `0.9.16` from `0.9.15`. Hoping someone can help me debug them.

Using Polkadot's `release-v0.9.15` and `release-v0.9.16` branches to build the binary and wasm.

My machine is:
`Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

My rustup version is:

```
1.57.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

The logs:

```
Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [38, 170, 57, 78, 234, 86, 48, 224, 124, 72, 174, 12, 149, 88, 206, 247, 128, 212, 30, 94, 22, 5, 103, 101, 188, 132, 97, 133, 16, 114, 201, 215]    
2022-02-21 11:33:20 Corrupted state at [38, 170, 57, 78, 234, 86, 48, 224, 124, 72, 174, 12, 149, 88, 206, 247, 128, 212, 30, 94, 22, 5, 103, 101, 188, 132, 97, 133, 16, 114, 201, 215]    
2022-02-21 11:33:21  Idle (3 peers), best: #56 (0x2b75…08af), finalized #34 (0x6f38…7c18), ⬇ 177.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 Corrupted state at [6, 222, 61, 138, 84, 210, 126, 68, 169, 213, 206, 24, 150, 24, 242, 45, 180, 180, 157, 149, 50, 13, 144, 33, 153, 76, 133, 15, 37, 184, 227, 133]    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 Running migration to v1 for session_historical with storage version StorageVersion(1)    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 Attempted to apply migration to v1 but failed because storage version is StorageVersion(1)    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for System    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Babe    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Timestamp    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Indices    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Balances    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for TransactionPayment    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Authorship    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Offences    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Historical    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Session    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Grandpa    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ImOnline    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for AuthorityDiscovery    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParachainsOrigin    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ⚠️ Configuration declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(1)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(2)`    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParasShared    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParaInclusion    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParaInherent    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParaScheduler    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Paras    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Initializer    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Dmp    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Ump    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Hrmp    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ⚠️ ParaSessionInfo declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(1)`    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParasDisputes    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Registrar    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Auctions    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Crowdloan    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Slots    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ParasSudoWrapper    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for AssignedSlots    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Sudo    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Mmr    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Beefy    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for MmrLeaf    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for ValidatorManager    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for BridgeRococoGrandpa    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for BridgeWococoGrandpa    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for BridgeRococoMessages    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for BridgeWococoMessages    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for BridgeRococoMessagesDispatch    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for BridgeWococoMessagesDispatch    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Collective    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Membership    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Utility    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Proxy    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ✅ no migration for Multisig    
2022-02-21 11:33:24 ⚠️ XcmPallet declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(0)`
```

My `polkadot-launch` setup is the following:

```
{
    "relaychain": {
        "bin": "polkadot915",
        "chain": "rococo-local",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "name": "alice",
                "wsPort": 9944,
                "port": 30444,
                "basePath": "validator1",
                "flags": [
                    "--rpc-cors=all",
                    "--execution=wasm",
                    "--wasm-execution=compiled"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "bob",
                "wsPort": 9955,
                "port": 30555,
                "basePath": "validator2",
                "flags": [
                    "--rpc-cors=all",
                    "--execution=wasm",
                    "--wasm-execution=compiled"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "charlie",
                "wsPort": 9966,
                "port": 30666,
                "basePath": "validator3",
                "flags": [
                    "--rpc-cors=all",
                    "--execution=wasm",
                    "--wasm-execution=compiled"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "genesis": {
            "runtime": {
                "runtime_genesis_config": {
                    "configuration": {
                        "config": {
                            "validation_upgrade_frequency": 10,
                            "validation_upgrade_delay": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "parachains": [
        {
            "bin": "polkadot-collator915",
            "chain": "statemine-dev",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "wsPort": 9801,
                    "port": 31201,
                    "name": "alice",
                    "flags": [
                        "--rpc-cors=all",
                        "--rpc-port=9971",
                        "--execution=wasm",
                        "-lcumulus-collator=trace,cumulus-network=trace,cumulus-consensus=trace",
                        "--wasm-execution=compiled"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "hrmpChannels": [
    ],
    "types": {},
    "finalization": false
}
```

First I do the client update from `polkadot915` to `polkadot916` without a problem.
Then the runtime upgrade produces the logs, which bricks block production after several minutes.
What could be the reason for such `Corrupted state at...` ?

This does not reproduce with `westend-local`, no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear this corrupted state was only in the logs after the RTU was started? Please try with more verbose logs, something like:

```
RUST_LOG=debug RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./target/release/polkadot --chain rococo-local -lruntime=debug
```

This *may* be an incorrect/missing migration, but not clear at first glance. I also think Rococo was restarted somewhere in the 15->16 timeframe. ([Overall delta](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/compare/release-v0.9.15...release-v0.9.16#diff-042f4804d206173992e7ca08b04b53ae8cc927a298722ecc44982c09e48ada76R51))

The [migrations for Rococo runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/compare/release-v0.9.15...release-v0.9.16#diff-0d5d1f76b24989edd69c12c2f482abdf143d8926f1b3191665378b848515d45cR162-R182) - is showing as your logs report for the expected migrations, but a breaking change in format for `sign_transaction` on bridges [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/compare/release-v0.9.15...release-v0.9.16#diff-8c207edd8ea24a9e13d6443c97ecb27e6695e7b6f5af02c2c60985f4224664f6L66) and a change in enum [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/compare/release-v0.9.15...release-v0.9.16#diff-e8c4d678b037a90eff3d9c72ed8338a72463902b9126c81522d5ff5c38320e3eR89) for the bridging may be the thing at fault. But unclear if that is it to me... Is this behavior you see reproducible?